# Can not assign a float to NSNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I have the following code in the m file of my root model:

```
-(id)init {
    if(self == [super init]) {
        self.rPrices = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.rPrices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];
}
    return self;
}

-(void)saveData:(NSMutableData *)data toFile:(NSString *)file {
float nR4;
nR4 = (some calculations ......)

[self.rPrices addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] numberWithFloat:nR4]];

}
```

I get the following error when I try to add the object:
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSPlaceholderNumber numberWithFloat:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Thanks

Comment: As a side note, you are not assigning `self` to the object returned by `[super init]`. It should be `((self = [super init]))`. The double parentheses indicate that the assignment is meant. Or, if you prefer `self = [super init]; if (self) { ... }`. Also, if `rPrices` is a retain/copy property, the statement `self.rPrices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` leaks. Also, the use of accessor methods in initializers is discouraged. Moreover, you are initializing `rPrices` twice, which is pointless. Change it to `rPrices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote @albertamg's comments by 1 for each bug he found in that code.

Comment: @Perception your comment is more valuable to me than those upvotes :)

Answer (score 8):

`numberWithFloat` is a class method, so you must use it like this:

```
[self.rPrices addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:nR4]];
```

This won't work however, because you've assigned an immutable `NSArray` to your `rPrices` property (immutable meaning that you can't modify it). You need to use `NSMutableArray` here.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, you are calling an `class method` on the object.

Try with changing the statement as below.

```
[self.rPrices addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:nR4]];
```

As also try with changing the way you construct your array.'

```
self.rPrices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
[self.rPrices addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil]];
```

Comment: Or simply `rPrices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];` (the usage of accessor methods is discouraged in initializers).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  In the root model I tried:   [self.rPrices replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)nR4]];
 and fixed the initialization and it worked.   But when I try to retrieve the value in a viewcontroller as follows:     RootModel *rm = [RootModel sharedModel];
    R4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [rm.rPrices objectAtIndex:0]];
I always get 0.00.

Comment: Actually the following NSLog also displays 0 as well.  [self.rPrices replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)nR4]];

    NSLog(@"%.2f", [self.rPrices objectAtIndex:0]);

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSNumber  numberWithFloat:nR4];
```

or

```
[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:nR4];
```

Comment: I think you meant `[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:nR4];`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize the array twice:

```
-(id)init { 
    self = [super init];

if (self != nil) { 
          //self.rPrices = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //this does not need 
          rPrices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil]; 
        } 
        return self; 
}


-(void)saveData:(NSMutableData *)data toFile:(NSString *)file {
    float nR4; 
    nR4 = (some calculations ......)
    [self.rPrices addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:nR4]];//This return an autoreleased OBJ so you don't need to call alloc

}
```

Comment: You are failing to assign `self` to the object returned by `[super init]`. It should be `((self = [super init]))`. The double parentheses indicate that the assignment is meant. Or, if you prefer `self = [super init]; if (self) { ... }` Also, you are initializing a `NSArray`, not a `NSMutableArray`, so when `saveData` attemps to add an object, it will throw an exception.

Comment: You're right... I have only focused the problem of the NSNumber.